# Label Encoding of multiple columns without using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there a simple way to label encode without using pandas for multiple columns?

Like using only numpy and sklearn's `preprocessing.LabelEncoder()`

Comment: AFAIK you would need to loop through your columns and convert each `string` column using `LabelEncoder`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to loop through the columns, converting them to numeric values, using `LabelEncoder`:

```
le = LabelEncoder()

cols_2_encode = [1,3,5] 

for col in cols_2_encode:
    X[:, col] = le.fit_tramsform(X[:, col])
```